# How to join any two specific threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to multi-threading. I would be glad, if someone could clear my doubt.

I have 3 threads t1, t2 and t3. If I use join on t1 like below, all other threads wait for t1 to finish. Is it possible that I could make just t2 to wait for t1 to finish, so that t1 and t3 can run concurrently?

```
    t1.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
```

Comment: Why not move the t3.start() command before the t1.join()? Then t1 and t3 will run concurrently.

Comment: Why not add the code for t2 to the end of t1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use join on `t1` like below, all other threads wait for `t1` to finish.

No. Only the thread executing the `t1.join()` call will wait for `t1` to finish. All other threads continue.

> Is it possible that I could make just `t2` to wait for `t1` to finish, so that `t1` and `t3` can run concurrently?

Execute the `t1.join()` from code running on the `t2` thread.

Answer (score -1):

You should `start` all the threads you want to run concurrently before calling `join` on any of them, as `join` will block `main` Thread until `joined` thread finishes. So, if you want to run `t1` and `t3`, and then start `t2` after first two are completed you should

```
//Start t1, t3
t1.start();
t3.start();
//Wait until t1 completes
t1.join();
//Wait until t3 completes, if this is required
t3.join();
//Start t2
t2.start();
//Wait until t2 completes, if this is required
t2.join();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes: you can do `t3.start()` before `t1.join()`:

```
t1.start();
t3.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
```